# JqueryMobile + Phonegap Android Device Back Button on external links

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, back-button, external-links

I am opening a link which is not part of my domain, let's say Using this piece of code
 `<a href="http://www.google.com" id="google"> <img src="images/google.png" ></a>'`

Now when the user clicks this, my app redirects to google. I am trying to use the hardware back button on android to go back to my application.

When i press the back button, i get this message on logcat: `10-20 19:54:21.375: E/Web Console(29676): Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at :1`

What i have been able to understand from this is that when the link is redirected to google, our app has lost control of the phonegap. Is it so? 
I  have tried using `data-rel="external"` with this link. But it doesn't makes any difference...

Following this, I have two problems i need help with

- When user presses hardware back button, go back to my app.
- When the google.com page is loading, user sees the page loading widget.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Phonegap ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser), it could help you with your problem, here an excerpt:

> The child browser allows you to display external web pages within your
>   PhoneGap application.
>
> A simple use case would be:
>
> - Users can post links, and you don't want your users to exit your app    to view the link.
>
> This command creates a popup browser that is shown in front of your
>   app, when the user presses the back button they are simply returned to
>   your app.

Comment: Thankyou for the reference. I have set up the plugin, but apparently it is not working as it should. Have you used it in any of your app?

Comment: No sorry I haven't, but I've seen many references from happy users of this plugin, try posting your error so we can help you.

Comment: I don't get any error, the childbrowser simply won't load. 
Can you please refer any working example which uses childbrowser in it?